# Have couple mistakes in python with while and elif statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop, range

```
from random import randint

play = "yes"
while play == "yes":
    choice = int(input("Would you like to play yourself(1) or let machine(2) play? press '1' or '2': "))

    if choice == 1:
        print("You chose to play yourself")
        num = randint(1,9999)
        counter = 0
        while True:
            num_guess = int(input("Guess the number: "))
            if num_guess == 0:
                print("Player has left the game")
                break
            else:
                if num_guess > num:
                    print("Your guess is too high")
                elif num_guess < num:
                    print("Your guess is too low")
                elif num_guess == num:
                    print("Yay,you found it")
                    print("It took you " + str(counter) + " tries to guess the number")
                    break
            counter += 1

    elif choice == 2:
        print("You chose to let the machine play")
        your_num = int(input("Enter your number: "))
        lowest = 1
        highest = 9999
        counter = 0
        machine_guess = randint(1,9999)
        if your_num == 0:
            you_sure = input("Are you sure you want to leave the game? yes or no: ")
            if you_sure == "yes":
                print("Player left the game")
                break
        else:   
            while True:
                print("My guess is ",machine_guess) 
                is_it_right = input("Is it too small(<) or too big(>) or machine found(=) the number?: ")
                if is_it_right == ">":
                    if machine_guess > your_num:
                        highest = machine_guess
                        counter += 1
                    else:
                        print("!!!Don't cheat!!!")
                        your_number = input("What was your number?: ")
                        print(str(machine_guess) +" < " + str(your_number) + ",so you should have written '<' instead of what you wrote.Continue ")
                elif is_it_right == "<":
                    if machine_guess < your_num:
                        lowest = machine_guess + 1
                        counter += 1 
                    else:
                        print("!!!Don't Cheat!!!")
                        your_number = input("What was your number?: ")
                        print(str(machine_guess) +" > " + str(your_number) + ",so you should have written '>' instead of what you wrote.Continue ")
                elif is_it_right == "=": 
                    if machine_guess == your_num:
                        if your_num == machine_guess:
                            counter += 1
                            print("Yayy,I found it")
                            print("It took me " + str(counter) + " tries to guess the number")
                        else:
                            print("You cheated and changed the number during the game.Please play fairly")
                            your_number = input("What was your number?: ")
                            print(str(machine_guess) +" = " + str(your_number) + ",so you should have written '=' instead of what you wrote ")
                        break
                elif is_it_right == 0:
                    you_sure = input("Are you sure you want to leave the game? yes or no: ")
                    if you_sure == "yes":
                        print("Player left the game")
                        break
                machine_guess = (lowest+highest)//2

    elif choice == 0:
        you_sure = input("Are you sure you want to leave the game? yes or no: ")
        if you_sure == "yes":
            print("Player has left the game")
            break

    request = input("Do you want to play again? Answer with 'yes' or 'no': ")
    if request == "no":
        print("You quitted the game")
        break
    elif request == 0:
        you_sure = input("Are you sure you want to leave the game? yes or no: ")
        if you_sure == "yes":
            print("Player left the game")
            break
```

This is my code for game "guess my number",here the complicated ones is me trying to make the program prevent user from cheating (It is a university task,due in 3 hours)
So choice 1 is when user decides to play game "guess my number" and 2nd choice when computer plays the game.The problem that I have is :

1. I can't make the code make the user input the number in range of(1,9999) and THEN continue the process
2. As you see I have a lot of "if ... == 0" --> .In task it is said that whenever(any of inputs) user types 0 the game has to stop.The others work well but the one in choice 2 the first if is not working

If somebody has solution for this,please help.I would be grateful

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having with #2? What error do you receive?

Comment: @Jtradfor after I choose choice 2,then proceed to write my number and after the computer starts guessing my number,I write 0 and it does not exit.I can't understand why,because it works fine in other situations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you want to ask a question repeatedly until the correct input is given, use a while loop

```
print("You chose to let the machine play")
your_num = -1
while your_num < 0 or your_num > 9999:
   your_num = int(input("Enter your number [0..9999]: "))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping with my 1st problem.I wanted to use range there,but I guess it is not the case.If you have any ideas with 2nd problem I would be really grateful,because I myself don't know why it is not working there

Comment: @stark Your solution to the first problem seems clearer than mine. I probably over-thought to catch the wrong inputs.

Comment: Are you saying that if you enter 0 it doesn't exit?

Comment: @stark yes it does not exit.But all the other ones work and I can't understand what is the problem with that one.When I write 0 it again and again outputs "My guess is ..."

Comment: @Jtradfor no,you choose choice 2 and then enter a number.After when the computer starts guessing,there when you enter 0,it does not exit

Comment: Wrong if.  It's the one that is inside two loops which is not working.  break only exits the inner loop.  Also set play='no' as suggested by @Cagri

Comment: @stark it still does not stop,even after i write play="no"

Comment: Change `is_it_right == 0` to `is_it_right == '0'`.  Do you see the difference?

Answer (score 1):

1- To force the user to input a number in the range of (1,9999), you must have an a condition like:

```
while True:
   try:
       num_guess= int(input("Enter your number in range 1-9999: "))
   except ValueError:
       print("That's not a number!")
   else:
       if 1 <= num_guess <= 9999:
           break
       else:
           print("Out of range. Try again")
```

Edit: I didn't understand which input you wanted to keep in the range of 1-9999. I gave answer with `num_guess` but you can use it with `your_num`, too.

2- Add `play = "no"` line to the condition when the user inputs 0:

```
 if your_num == 0:
            you_sure = input("Are you sure you want to leave the game? yes or no: ")
            if you_sure == "yes":
                print("Player left the game")
                play = "no"
                break
```

Comment: Break should end the loop regardless of if play is set to "no," shouldn't it? I think the issue is he needs to use raw_input instead of input so that the conditional is met when the user types yes without quotation marks. But then again I might not entirely be understanding the problem for question #2.

Comment: `input()` is the updated Python3 version of `raw_input()` from Python 2. I don't think that is the problem

Comment: yes break should end it and it does end in other ones.But in that one which I mentioned it does not exit,I can't understand why

Comment: Yes, I think break should if ended. So what I didn't quite understand what do you mean by "does not exist". Does it continue to execute the following lines, or does it re-enters the while loop? If the case is re-entering, `play = "no"` should work.